# Why we can multiple dx on both side in df/dx equation

Tags: derivatives

I'm reading about [Total Derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative) when learning machine learning concept. I'm reading to this:
[image]

The thing I don't know is: As my knowledge, `df/dt` looks like a "notation" than a variable. But in this, I see that we can multiple by both side `dt`. It looks like `dt` is acting as variable. I don't get this point. Can explain for me, why can we do this. And what does the meaning of `dt`when it stands as single variable.

Thanks

Comment: As far as I know, no introductory calculus book or differential equations book has an entirely satisfactory (or correct) explanation of what $dx$ means. This point has been brought up by [many](https://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/lg5/Rota.pdf).

Comment: I think it is a notation/mnemonic that is true in some limit of small differences, it seems to be described as such here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function . It could be that $dt$ is a (dual space) base vector for the dual space that are made of functions that map vectors to scalars, too.

Comment: @Batman thanks. I maybe really means why we can "multiple dt" by both side as `dt` looks like variable. I think there are some mathematical reasons behind. Just because I don't know how to express that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of "differential" has the equation

$$dy = f'(x) \; dx$$

or $$dy = \frac{dy}{dx} \; dx.$$

It looks like cancellation, but it isn't really.  But it does say that 
whenever you have

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \mbox{crud}$$

you can multiply by $dx$ to get

$$\frac{dy}{dx} \; dx= \mbox{crud} \; dx.$$

Then you can use the equation from the definition of differential to *replace* 
$\frac{dy}{dx} \; dx$ by $dy$.  So it's replacement, not cancellation.

Edit:  In the definition of "differential", $dx$ and $dy$ are new variables.  The equation $dy = f'(x) \; dx$ shows what the relation ship is between those variables and $x$ (and sometimes $y$, too.)  If you're given a specific point $(x,y)$ on the graph of $y=f(x)$, then you can think of the origin of the $dx-dy$-plane as being on that point, with the $dx$-axis parallel to the $x-axis$ and the $dy$-axis parallel to the $y$-axis.  The $dx-dy$-plane is a little traveling coordinate system that goes along the function.  The equation $dy = f'(x) \; dx$ is the equation of a line through the origin of that space.

Comment: thanks. I understood your point about this is a replacement :D Just a little thing I haven't understood yet: `dy/dx = crud`. "We can multiply by dx" to get `dy/dx * dx = crud * dx`.  The thing I don't know is: why we can multiply by dx. It make think that "dx" something likes variable too.

Comment: I added some more comments in the edit.

Comment: thanks. I have read this link: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function and understanding your point about "dx-dy" is the new origin. So in the equation `dy/dx * dx = crud dx`.  Can I understand as it is a "cancellation" instead of "replacement" ? Because on plan Oxy, the "cancellation" is normal.

Comment: It's a problem with notation.  $dy/dx$ doesn't mean division, normally.  But if you take $dy$ and $dx$ to be new variables, then one could, in theory write $dy/dx$ and mean division; but nobody ever does.

Comment: thanks. I understood your point :D